# Сырой или зелёный кофе?

Tags: грамотная-речь

По-английски сомнений не возникает — *green coffee,* что буквально и означает *зелёный.* В своё время я решил, что не должно быть кальки с английского и по-русски правильно называть такой кофе *сырым.*

Однако Google даёт намного больше запросов именно на *зелёный кофе* — 342 000 против всего 8 000 на *сырой кофе.*

Так как же всё-таки правильно?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно и так, и так. Например, ГОСТ Р 51450-99, по большей части составленного ещё в СССР, дается на "[зеленый (сырой) кофе](http://standartgost.ru/g/%D0%93%D0%9E%D0%A1%D0%A2_%D0%A0_51450-99)". Если говорить о причинах большей популярности "зелёный кофе", то помимо вполне понятной кальки (в России всё-таки кофе не растёт), скорее всего сказывается то, что к зерновым "сырой" вообще нечасто употребляют

Comment: Спасибо, Марк!!

Answer (score 2):

В стандартах РФ закреплено наименование "зелёный (сырой)". В пользу "зелёного" кофе говорит то, существует и одноимённый вариант напитка:

http://greencoffeecup.ru/kak-pit-zelenyj-kofe.php

То есть это не просто сырьё, а полуфабрикат, отличающийся от привычного "просто кофе в зёрнах" способом подготовки. "Сырой" этот кофе с точки зрения традиционно более распространённого у нас черного кофе из обжаренных зёрен. Сравнительно мало распространён у нас и зелёный чай, с которым языковых вопросов не возникает - о нём известно гораздо больше, чем о зелёном кофе в виде напитка. Он тоже отличается способом сушки. В Китае, где чёрный чай используется мало, он буквально называется "красным" (он так выглядит заваренным) - аналогично можно перенести на кофе цвет зелёных зёрен, с которыми мы редко имеем дело и в большинстве своём не видим в напитке: первое, что мы можем сказать о зёрнах по внешнему виду - это непривычный цвет.

Comment: Спасибо, Александр!

Comment: Чай, кстати, бывает ещё и голубой, и жёлтый, и белый (почки пуэра). :)

Comment: Я ещё всё-таки сомневаюсь, что за напитком такое название (зелёный кофе) действительно повсеместно закрепилось... То есть вполне может быть и так, но из Вашей ссылки это не очевидно, к сожалению.

Comment: В своё время был специально разработанный "жёлтый" грузинский чай, с каким-то своим способом обработки (возможно, и смесь с зелёным). Недолго просуществовал, правда.

Comment: Есть жёлтый китайский чай: http://moychay.ru/catalog/zheltyj_chaj. А вот голубого действительно нету (просто я думал, что улун так называют). Хороший магазин, кстати, рекомендую. Надеюсь, это не воспримут как рекламу. Мне-то выгоды от этого никакой. :)

Comment: По кофе я не большой специалист, а насчет чая могу сказать. Цвет напитка не всегда совпадает с названием, тут часто ориетнируются на цвет сухого чайного листа. Но перво-наперво - на китайскую традицию, понять которою не всегда просто. В целом же цвет чая - это сорт, качество. Определяется прежде всего той частью чайного куста, с которой берутся листы для сырья и (в меньшей степени) - спелостью. Последующая технология тут не главное. Это я к тому, что какая-либо аналогия с кофе вряд ли уместна.  А вообще это лучше на переводческих ресурсах обсуждать. Здесь у всех чистые имхи максимум.